# Is "funciones de retorno" best translated as "return functions" or "callback functions"?

Tags: traducción

In this phrase:

> Las funciones de retorno de los métodos Meteor siempre tienen dos
>   argumentos, error y result.

Is **"funciones de retorno"** best translated as **"return functions"** or **"callback functions"**?

Comment: A function can return another one, this will be a return function. When referring to callback functions we are speaking of functions that ar called when something happens. With the meteor context and arguments for error and result, the best translation is callback functions, as they receive the error value to return if an error happens and the result to return if the call where successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If related to computer programming "callback functions" works best in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Hay un proyecto en github para traducir el libro *Discover Meteor*: ["Discover Meteor ES"](https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/DiscoverMeteor_Es). Los colaboradores de este proyecto parecen haber optado por usar [`función de retorno'](https://github.com/DiscoverMeteor/DiscoverMeteor_Es/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=retorno)

> Hemos colocado nuestra llamada de enrutamiento `Router.go()` dentro de la **función de retorno** de la llamada.
>
> Las funciones de retorno de los métodos Meteor siempre tienen dos argumentos, `error` y `result`.

Supongo que ese es el ejemplo que encontraste para la pregunta. "A callback function" debe traducirse como *función de retorno*. Estos objetos son una función, que usamos como parámetro en la llamada otra función, con el sentido de "cuando se ejecute la primera función va a llamar a esta otra (la *callback function*) que indico en este parámetro".

"return functions", aunque no se usa en programación (en todo caso se diría *function return* para referirse a aquello que va  devolver una función) indicaría algo diferente. "return" es algo que devuelve la función, mientras que "callback" expresa "invocado al ejecutarse la función". Esa *callback function* podría hacer algo, sin necesariamente devolver un valor útil.